# how to get PID and export it to a log file

Tags: python-2.7, logging, pid

im trying to log the process that are running with this code.
I was able to print out but im unsure how to input this into a log file

iv looked at sample code and have gotten one some code to log but that was with some static variables.
if I remove logging.debug and put in print it will

```
import logging
import win32com.client
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="test1.log",
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s"
    )
wmi=win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')
for p in wmi.InstancesOf('win32_process'):
    logging.debug ("p.Name", p.Properties_('ProcessId')), \
        int(p.Properties_('UserModeTime').Value)+int(p.Properties_('KernelModeTime').Value)
    children=wmi.ExecQuery('Select * from win32_process where     ParentProcessId=%s' %p.Properties_('ProcessId'))
```

thank you in advance with any and all help 
im expecting to put a timestamp with the PID

Comment: I do plan to go and make a loop so when the process end it will time stamp the end

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file)

If you define your logging config before executing .info, .debug etc

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

It will log to a file.

Logging variables should look something like this:

```
logging.warning('%s before you %s', 'Look', 'leap!')
```

In your case, use %s for Strings, %d for Integers

Comment: thanks man if its alright
what would you recommend if I don't want the same log repeating ?
should I hold the next log as a variable or is there a way to check a log file before adding in another input

Comment: AFAIK your code should not repeat the same log again and again, since you only loop through your processes once. It might be that the same gets logged due to often running the programm. add logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG) to always create a new file instead of appending the logs. If this doesn't answer your question, i would use a variable